# I can't figure it out why its not working

Tags: discord, discord.js

My ban command isn't working. Can somebody help me? It's very important to me.
This is my first bot and I want it to be really good.

Code:

```js
module.exports = {
name: "ban", 
aliases: ["banuser"], 
execute(client, message, args) { 
if (message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) let User = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]) 
if (!User) return message.channel.send("Meg kell nevezned egy szemelyt!") 
if (User.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("Nem tudtam kitiltani a felhasznalat") 
let banReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
if (!banReason) banReason = "None"
User.ban({reason: banReason}) 
}
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\marce\Discord Bot\commands\ban.js:6 
     let User = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
     ^^^

 SyntaxError: Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context
```

Comment: Could you provide more details and clarify your question? In the state your question is currently in, it's hard to diagnosticate the problem.

Comment: Okay, I posted 2 more images about the code, and I can't ban because of a dot..   Before the ban there is a dot! If its there I cant launch the bot... If there is no dots then the ban is not working..

Comment: Please don't post images of code because we cannot test the code ourselves, and may cause the question to lose crucial information in the future due to deletion of the images. Thanks! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Thanks for the link.. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable before the `if` function. For example:

```js
if (1+1===2) let test = 1 // this will return an error
```

```js
let test;
if (1+1===2) test = 1 // this will not return an error
```

In your situation, you need to change

```js
if (message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBER') let User = // ...
```

to

```js
let User;
if (message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBER') User = // ...
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me.. I tried it, it shows the same thing in cmd...   I can show, what does it say, if it would help :D

Comment: Yes, please do that 

Comment: Too long :D  I can send it by 2

Comment: C:\Users\marce\DiscordBot\commands\ban.js:7
        let User = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context
←[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)←[39m

Comment: ←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marce\DiscordBot\main.js:19:21)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)←[39m

Comment: module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    aliases: ["kickuser"],
        execute(client, message, args){
            let User;
            if (message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS"))
        let User = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0])

Comment: if (!User) return message.channel.send("Meg kell nevezned egy személyt!")
        if (User.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("Nem tudtam kirúgni a felhasználót")
        let kickReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
        if (!kickReason) {
        kickReason = "None"
        }

        User.kick({reason: kickReason})
            }
        }

Comment: This is it, and this is the same as the ban!